# Is there a way to use Java generic types to write sorting algorithms?

Tags: java, sorting, generics

I've been relearning Java after a long time, and I'm trying out writing some sorting algorithms. The (rather outdated) textbook I have uses the Comparable interface to sort objects. Since Comparables are now generic types, doing this gives me a lot of warnings about raw types when compiling. After some research, it looks like I can do something like, for example:

```
public class Sorting
{
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void quickSort(T[] list, int start, int end)
    {
        /*...*/
        while((list[left].compareTo(list[pivot]) < 0) && (left != right)) // for example
            left++;
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that the naive way of calling this method does not work:

```
public class SortingTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Produces an error, cannot create arrays of generic types
        Comparable<Integer>[] list = new Comparable<Integer>[100];

        /* fill the array somehow */

        Sorting.quickSort(list, 0, 99);
    }
}
```

It is illegal to create an array of generic types in Java. The problem only gets worse if I try to implement a merge sort, since that requires creating arrays of Comparable types inside the merge sort method itself.

Is there any way to handle this situation elegantly?

Comment: You can use the Comparator interface http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: This is not the question … he want to write its own generic sorter ! You can reopen.

Comment: Note that this question does not appear to be about the signature  or implementation of the sorting method, but about how to create one of the actual arguments to the method.

Comment: for best results, use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `T` *extends* `Comparable<T>`. It doesn't have to *be* `Comparable<T>`.

So you could, for example, create an array of Integers, because `Integer` implements `Comparable<Integer>`.

```
Integer[] list = new Integer[100];
/* fill the array somehow */
Sorting.quickSort(list, 0, 99);
```

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I didn't realize that. Is it possible to adapt this to fix the merge sort problem, though? I can't just make the new arrays within the merge sort method be Integer (or Double, etc.) arrays, because then it can't act on arbitrary types.

Comment: @QuantumCop - You can't create an instance of a generic array, because of type erasure - the actual generic type parameters are not available at runtime, but you would need them to create the array. So in-place sorting is easier. For mergesort, there is an ugly hack you could use for temporary arrays - create `Object[]`s and cast them. A cleaner option would be to use `ArrayList<T>`, which hides that same hack.

Comment: @QuantumCop - I see this is your first question. Welcome to StackOverflow! You can click the up arrow on multiple answers you find useful. You can click the checkmark outline to the left of the answer you find the most useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an array of `Object` and then cast to an array of `T`. Note that this will create a compiler warning.